# Pending Intent for more than one notification

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent

I have app which sends notifications, I used this code for pending intent

```
  Intent myIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),MainActivity.class);
  myIntent.putExtra("link",Link);

  PendingIntent intent2 =  
  PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1,myIntent, 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

and it worked nice for the first time, but I use this piece of code inside a method that invokes every 1 minute.

The problem is that the `link` variable changes from one to another.

and when I get the data in the `MainActivity` I found the last link only, all the notifications created has the last link.

and I don't know how to avoid this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are sending the same request code for your pending intents. These codes are defined as the 2nd parameter of your Pending intent declaration

Change

```
PendingIntent intent2 =  
  PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),1,myIntent, 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

To:

```
PendingIntent intent2 =  
  PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),UNIQUE_INT_VALUE_FOR_EVERY_CALL,myIntent, 
  PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);
```

If you use the same id, the intent will be reused and you will only get the last data rather than getting new data for every call.

Comment: Great happy to help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try This,

```
  PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(GCMNotificationIntentService.this, 0, notificationIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

Answer (score 0):

In **Kotlin**

Make a notification

```
val builder = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, CHANNEL_ID)
```

For **one and more** just change the **request Code** number:

```
    val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context,
System.currentTimeMillis().toInt(),intent, 0)
```

then

```
builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
```